# How to implement CMSIS DSP Library in Cortex M3 (STM32F103)

Tags: arm, signal-processing, stm32, cortex-m, cmsis

I'm trying to follow [these steps](https://community.st.com/s/article/configuring-dsp-libraries-on-stm32cubeide) in order to use the FFT for my project, but every tutorial I follow keeps giving me the same error `region 'FLASH' overflowed by 49836 bytes`.
I understand that the microcontroller I'm using doesn't have enough space in it's memory to hold all the library (since it's full of tables to speed up the math) but it doesn't make sense that ST won't provide a native way of doing signal processing for Cortex M3 microcontrollers.

I would like an efficient way of doing FFTs with this microcontroller. Even Arduinos can do this with their own limitations.

Microcontroller specs:
STM32F103C8 (the board is a BluePill), 64KB Flash, 20KB RAM.

Comment: This tutorial is for the micro having 1MB (actually 2MB in two banks) FLASH. ST rather does not think that anyone will do any DSP using the STMF1.  You need to use other DSP libraries or write the functions yourself (or modify the existing ones to fit your hardware). First step - reduce the table sizes and use math to interpolate the values between.

Comment: CMSIS has nothing to do with code efficiency or even being able to fit in any particular device.   Likewise one does not expect DSP code to fit in an mcu despite there being high level libraries.  I think the issue here is expectations not the library.

Comment: Do not forget that Cortex M3 doesn't have a Floating Point Unit (FPU). So when you are using float numbers, it simulates with software occupies more memory and used more processing power. So do not use Cortex M3 devices with floating-point libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the CMSIS github repo and generate the library without the tables that go unused. That might help. Otherwise try a different library preferably one that doesn't precalculate the bit twiddle tables before hand at the cost of performance.